# Can these plural and singular forms be exchanged?

Tags: american-english, british-english, plural-forms, singular

> Do you work **on Sundays**?
>  What do you usually do **at the
>   weekend**?
>  (Essential Grammar in Use)

Can the plural and singular forms be exchanged like these?

> Do you work *on the Sunday*?
>   What do you usually do *at weekends*?

Comment: *At the weekend* and *at weekends* are BrE.  *On the weekend* and *on weekends* are AmE.  I'm not sure whether *work on the Sunday* in acceptable in BrE, but it's wrong in AmE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can say *on Sunday* and *on weekends*, or *at weekends*. Informally, or in North American, you could also say "Do you work Sunday(s)?"

> On Monday I do yoga.

As said from snailboat, *at the weekend* is British English, equivalent to *on the weekend* used in North American English.

> The office is closed at the weekend.

> The office is closed on the weekend.

Comment: The question "Do you work on Sunday?" sounds like it may be asking about one specific Sunday. The question "Do you usually work on Sunday?", though, unambiguously asks about Sundays in general.